# Error when calling global variables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to declare a global variable with a value and access it in the functions.

I'm done below code but showing **Undefined variable: msg1** in the login function.

Please help me to do this.

```
    class loader extends CI_Controller {

    public $msg1 = "login error";

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function login() {
        $result = $this->login_model->login();
        if (!$result) {
            $msg = $this->$msg1;
            $this->index($msg) ;
        } else {
            //something here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `$this->msg1` remove `$`

Comment: `$msg1` is not global variable. It is public property.

Comment: does it's working after using @Fast Snail's Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
class loader extends CI_Controller {

public $msg1 = "login error";

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

public function login() {
    $result = $this->login_model->login();
    if (!$result) {
        $msg = $this->msg1;
        $this->index($msg) ;
    } else {
        //something here
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$` from `$msg1` in login function

```
$msg = $this->msg1;
```